# zlibc: package not found

Tags: apt, package-management, pop-os

I am using Pop!_OS and I want to install a bunch of tools, during the process, I get an error telling me that there is no package called `zlibc`.

`apt search zlibc` gives me no results. How can I set this up?
I am trying to install [this set of tools](https://gitlab.com/incoresemi/utils/common_utils/-/raw/master/pesu_install/inst_toolchain.sh).

Comment: zlibc → https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=zlibc&searchon=names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zlibc` is obsolete and was [removed from Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/958293), and thus from Ubuntu and Pop!_OS.

The error shouldn’t matter; the installation script says

```
sudo apt-get install zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev  # Ubuntu only (ignore if gives error)
```